# Why we need to setup AWS and POSTgres db when we deploy our app using Heroku?

Tags: django, postgresql, api, github, heroku

I'm building a web api by watching the youtube video below and until the AWS S3 bucket setup I understand everything fine. But he first deploy everything locally then after making sure everything works he is transferring all static files to AWS and for DB he switches from SQLdb3 to POSgres.

[django portfolio](https://youtu.be/)

I still don't understand this part why we need to put our static files to AWS and create POSTgresql database even there is an SQLdb3 default database from django. I'm thinking that if I'm the only admin and just connecting my GitHub from Heroku should be enough and anytime I change something in the api just need to push those changes to github master and that should be it.

Why we need to use AWS to setup static file location and setup a rds (relational data base) and do the things from the beginning. Still not getting it!

Can anybody help to explain this ?
Thanks

Comment: I know I kinda jump in the subject from the middle but maybe expertises will get it quickly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Databases

There are several reasons a video guide would encourage you to switch from SQLite to a database server such as MySQL or PostgreSQL:

1. SQLite is great but doesn't scale well if you're expecting a lot of traffic
2. SQLite doesn't work if you want to distribute your app accross multiple servers. Going back to Heroky, if you serve your app with multiple Dynos, you'll have a problem because each Dyno will use a distinct SQLite database. If you edit something through the admin, it will happen on one of this databases, at random, leading to inconsistencies
3. Some Django features aren't available on SQLite

SQLite is the default database in Django because it works out of the box, and is extremely fast and easy to use in local/development environments for prototyping.

However, it is usually not suited for production websites. Additionally, while it can be tempting to store your `sqlite.db` file along with your code, for instance in a git repository, it is considered a bad practice because your database can contain sensitive data (such as passwords, usernames, emails, etc.). Hence, a strict separation between your code and data is a good practice.

Another way to put it is that your code and your data have different lifecycles. You want to be able to edit data in your database without redeploying your code, and update your code without touching your database.

Even if you can remove public access to some files through GitHub, this is not a good practice because when you work in a team with multiple developpers, developpers may have access to the code but not the production data, because it's usually sensitive. If you work with 5 people and each one of them has a copy of your database, it means the risk to lose it or have it stolen is 5x higher ;)

## Static files

When you work locally, Django's built-in `runserver` command handles the serving of static assets such as CSS, Javascript and images for you.

However, this server is not designed for production use either. It works great in development, but will start to fail very fast on a production website, that should handle way more requests than your local version.

Because of that, you need to host these static files somewhere else, and AWS is one place where you can do that. AWS will serve those files for you, in a very efficient way. There are other options available, for instance configuring a reverse proxy with Nginx to serve the files for you, if you're using a dedicated server.

As far as I can tell, the progression you describe from the video is bringing you from a local, development enviromnent to a more efficient and scalable production setup. That is to be expected, because it's less daunting to start with something really simple (SQLite, Django's built-in `runserver`), and move on to more complex and abstract topics and tools later on.

Comment: This is a great answer for clearing the fog :) but I did not understand some parts as we can set github private(no public access to db and static files) to secure some sensitive information and its not clear why we cannot deploy the api just from the github connection. Actually yes I got some error when I just try to deploy from github branch no AWS connection and when I do the AWS connection the page started to working as he showed. But why still we need to use AWS or any other service ? just why github is not enough?

Comment: I've added clarification as for why you shouldn't store your database with your code. As for the static files, it's really a different matter: these are usually not sensitive. It's just that they need to be served somehow, just like Heroku serve the other parts of your application, and you have to pick something for that (AWS, in the case of your tutorial)

Comment: I'm not expecting any high frequency traffic to my webpage. not expecting to use multiple dynos. I'm really ok to deploy the app from the github but your answer is saying NO! it will not work! because of the how django works in production. Am I understanding it correctly ?

Comment: Of course, you can do that, it's your project after all (and I've certainly done that in the past ;). However, I think the progression in the video makes sense because it shows you best practices that are used in professional teams.

Comment: Ok, makes sense now. I do appreciate such a great answer with lots of details. I encountered some error when I just use github only and when I do the AWS static file setup and rds setup it started to work. and also AWS charges after 750hrs right? so after a month it is going to charge or everytime heroku wants to connect static files ? which one? I do appriciate if you share your knowledge on this :) I dont want to make  pezos rich :))

Comment: You're welcome, I know all of this can be really confusing.

I'm not really familiar with AWS S3 pricing, but as far as I can remember, you'll pay depending of the amount of data (static files) you'll store there, and maybe of the traffic AWS will serve for you. Since it's only a bunch of small static files, probably less than 1 USD/month, but you should have a look yourself.

Never used Heroku myself, but I expect their pricing depends on the Dyno performance/hours of usage.

Comment: what was the services you have used instead of heroku?

Comment: Mostly my own Virtual Private Server (you can rent cheap ones on services such as Digital Ocean) and dedicated servers, because I also wanted to learn about system administration as well as development, and services Heroku and AWS kind of take that away from you (which is totally fine, I just wanted to learn that too)